# Getting the Bowler Count to Display in League RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a list of Leagues that that I want to display the number of bowlers for in each entry. For Example:

[image]

I want to display a count of the number of bowlers in each list under each League name in the list. For Example:

[image]

This is meant to be a quick view about each League.

I tried to accomplish this with the following code:

**DatabaseHelper**

```
//Getting Number of Bowlers in League
    public String leagueBowlerCount(String leagueId)
    {
        
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = 0;
    if(null != cursor)
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
    cursor.close();


db.close();
return String.valueOf(count);
}
```

**League Adapter**

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView id;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView baseScore;
        public TextView basePercentage;
        public TextView bowlerCount;
        TextView timestamp;
        public TextView buttonViewOption;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            if (!(itemView instanceof AdView)) {
                id = view.findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId);
                name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueName );
                baseScore = view.findViewById( R.id.tvBaseScore);
                basePercentage = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBaseScorePercentage);
                bowlerCount = view.findViewById(R.id.tvNumberOfBowlers);
                timestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
                buttonViewOption = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewOptions);
            }
        }
    }

    public LeagueAdapter(Context context, List<League> leaguesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.leaguesList = leaguesList;
        mainActivity = (Activity) context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public LeagueAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        AdView adview;
        MyViewHolder holder;

        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
            adview = new AdView(mainActivity);
            adview.setAdSize( AdSize.BANNER);

            // this is the good adview
            adview.setAdUnitId(mainActivity.getString(R.string.admob_ad_id));

            float density = mainActivity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
            AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
            adview.setLayoutParams(params);

            // dont use below if testing on a device
            // follow https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en to setup testing device
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adview.loadAd(request);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(adview);

        }else{
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_league, parent, false);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        }
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(position % 10 != 5) {
            League league = leaguesList.get(position);
            int id = league.getId();
            String leagueId = String.valueOf(id);
            holder.id.setText(leagueId);
            holder.name.setText(league.getName());
            holder.baseScore.setText(league.getBasisScore());
            holder.basePercentage.setText(league.getBaseScorePercentage());
            holder.bowlerCount.setText(db.leagueBowlerCount(leagueId));
            holder.timestamp.setText(formatDate(league.getTimestamp()));

            holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.league_options_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                 public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.profile:
                            //Log.d("leagueId", String.valueOf(position));
                            //int leagueId = league.getId();
                            ((MainActivity) context).openDialog(true, leaguesList.get(position), position);
                            break;
                            case R.id.delete:
                                ((MainActivity) context).deleteLeague(position);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I have been messing around with this for a number of days, I cannot figure out why this will not work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am thinking that there is probably a much easier way of accomplishing this that I am not aware of.

In the logcat I am seeing the following message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ca.vogl.r.tenpinbowlingcompanion.database.DatabaseHelper.leagueBowlerCount(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.
```

As was pointed out below, the error seems to be happening in leagueBowlerCount(), which is listed above.

After making making the following addition to the onBindViewHolder : db = new DatabaseHelper (mainActivity).  I am seeing values where I should be but they are not correct.  See images below.

[image]

Test League 1 (there are three bowlers, one is hidden by the test ad)

[image]

Test League 2 (there is only 1 bowler)

[image]

Test League 3 (there are three bowlers, one is hidden by the test ad)

[image]

So basically you should be seeing a 3 for Test League 1, a 1 for Test League 2 and a 3 for Test League 3

So it now seems that the problem is with the leagueBowlercount function that I wrote. It is not getting the counts that are associated only to the individual league Id

Comment: The code is incorrect anyway.  The code delimits the leagueId as a string with a single quote, but then there is no closing single quote.  Do you not get an error from that SQL code?  It looks like leagueId is numeric, so there is no need for the quotes.  Sqlite can be forgiving by automatically converting the string back to an integer, but it is best to code for the proper data type to start with, so just remove any string quotes for the LeagueId.

Comment: No the leagueId is a String, I am converting it in the onBindViewHolder because in the Bowler table it is being stored as a String value.  As for the missing single quote it was a copy and paste issue.  (between the user and the keyboard.  In the logcat I see `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ca.vogl.r.tenpinbowlingcompanion.database.DatabaseHelper.leagueBowlerCount(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`  I know that the Textview exists and has been associated to the holder.  I have put the TextView above.

Comment: I have looked at the link you provided above and I don't see much difference from what I have been attempting to do, unless I am missing something.  Also I understand the the aggregate queries for MIN, MAX and AVG,  does COUNT work the same way?

Comment: Okay, please update the question with details of the errors.  Don't leave that critical detail in comments.  Such error details should always be included first thing with the question.  It is apparent that some error is occurring in `leagueBowlerCount()`, so the other code is likely irrelevant and excessive.  The full XML layout is also not necessary.

Comment: It is worth learning how the aggregate functions and queries work, but that detail is beyond this question.  It is very inefficient to retrieve all columns (i.e. `SELECT * ...`) and all rows just to count them.

Comment: In the league Adapter I am getting the leagueId from the League Table which is an integer.  I am writing it to the Bowler table later on as a String.  Which is why you are see it as an integer above.  This is also why I am converting it to a String for the Bowler table.  No the League Id can never be null.  There must always be an id for the league.

Comment: Okay, the whole int vs string id value just seems problematic to me, probably makes code more complicated and buggy than needs and likely causes problems with joining tables in the database, so I suggest making it have the same simple integer value across the board...

Comment: But I digress, because the error detail you provided is about the object you are calling leagueBowlerCount() on, not the method itself or its arguments.  In other words, the variable `db` in the line `holder.bowlerCount.setText(db.leagueBowlerCount(leagueId));` is apparently null.

Comment: Not sure how it could be null since I am declaring it before the onCreate() as such: _public DatabaseHelper db;_

Comment: I am not sure if this the correct, but I added _db = new DatabaseHelper(mainActivity);_ to the onBindViewHolder and the error went away and I now see values for each list item.  How ever they are not correct.  See images above.

Comment: This question has already prompted too much discussion.  You need to ask a new question after researching the problem.  You finally found the cause of the original error.  It is not appropriate to continually update the question with new details.

Comment: Can you please repost the link to the article that you posted earlier.  You removed it after taking away the duplicate comment.   I believe this will be helpful.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you are returning the id of the first selected bowler rather than the row count.

That is you, after checking the number of rows is greater than 0, move to the first row and then use `count = cursor.getInt(0);` which will be the value stored in the first column of the first row that has been extracted.

try using :-

```
public String leagueBowlerCount(String leagueId)
{
    String rv = "0";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Bowler.TABLE_NAME,new String[]{"count(*)"},Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + "=?",new String[]{leagueId},null,null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(0));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return rv;
}
```

This uses the aggregate function **count** to extract the number of rows for the respective league.

- Note the above code is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run and may therefore have some errors.

Alternatively you could use :-

```
public String leagueBowlerCount(String leagueId)
    {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return String.valueOf(count);
}
```

In regard to your code :-

```
int count = 0;
if(null != cursor)
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        count = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
cursor.close();
```

- Checking for a null Cursor is useless, as a Cursor returned from an SQLiteDatabase method, such as rawQuery, will never be null. Instead a valid, perhaps empty, Cursor will be returned.
- Additionally checking if a Cursor has rows using the `getCount` method and then using `moveToFirst` is not needed as just using `if (cursor.moveToFirst) {.....}` is sufficient as if there are no rows the `moveToFirst` method will return false, as the move cannot be actioned.

Comment: MikeT once again your help is greatly appreciated, the first sample code you supplied above works like a charm.  Thank you so much!!